# Can I program the LUT5_D in virtex-5 FPGA with 2bit 2-to-1 mux functions?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am trying to fit a 2-bit 2-to-1 mux into one LUT. It seems that `LUT5_D` has 5 inputs and 2 outputs. Can I program the LUT as what I want?

I have used `LUT3`, `LUT4` before. From the virtex-5 library guide, it seems that to instantiate `LUT5_D`, I need to program a proper init value, but there is only one init value to program, so only one of the outputs will actually be used? Or will both of the outputs give the same value any time?

```
LUT5_D #(
.INIT(32'h55550f0f),
) LUT5_D_inst
(.O(O), // General LUT output (1-bit)
.LO(LO), // Local LUT output (1-bit)
.I0(I0), // LUT input (1-bit)
.I1(I1), // LUT input (1-bit)
.I2(I2), // LUT input (1-bit)
.I3(I3), // LUT input (1-bit)
.I4(SEL));
```

Comment: There's already a 2-to-1 mux in the slice, why don't you use that? (Take a look at FPGA editor). What happens when you implement the code above? From what I can tell, you'll always get an output  of 1.

Comment: How to use that 2-to-1 mux exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LUT5_D` is not going to do what you want: the two outputs are identical (the table in the libraries guide shows this).

The 2 output option is the `LUT6_2`:

[image: LUT6_2]

For your application, you have two inputs (A and B) each with two bits (0,1) and an output (Y) also with two bits.

- Use `I0` as the select input
- Wire `I5` to always select the top LUT5 (logic 1 IIRC).
- Wire up `I4:1` as `A0`,`B0`,`A1`,`B1`.
- `O6` is then `Y0`, `O5` is `Y1`

I leave it as an exercise to the interested reader to come up with the INIT values which:

- cause the top LUT5 to MUX between `I4` and `I3` based on `I0`
- cause the bottom LUT5 to MUX between `I2` and `I1` based on `I0`

Answer (score 1):

Don't program INIT values. LUT_MAP is much easier and more maintainable:

```
(* LUT_MAP="yes" *)
module mux2(sel, a, b, o);
    input  sel;
    input  a;
    input  b;
    output o;

    assign o = (~sel&a) | (sel & b);
endmodule
```

With a common sel input signal, the mux2 above can be packed 8 to a (four 6-LUT) slice by splitting each of the four 6-LUTs into 2 5-LUTs.

Comment: the LUT map you provide seems to be a 2-to-1 mux. Do you mean that a and b are both 2 bits? I dont see 8 2-to-1 mux being pack into one slices after place and route.

Comment: If you place (* RLOC="X0Y0" *) constraints on the eight instances of mux2, the mapper will pack the resulting 8 LUT3s into one slice. (I just verified this.)